# how to enable only IPv6 on interface

Tags: networking

I have a linux server that has multiple network interfaces, on one of them I want to completely disable IPv4, so that it only has IPv6 there. Is it possible? How?

Note: I don't want to disable IPv4 entirely for whole kernel, other interfaces still need IPv4 address. Just this testing interface needs to have only IPv6 address and no IPv4.

Comment: Not setting an IPv4 address on the interface would effectively disable it for IPv4 wouldn't it?

Comment: @mtak no idea, maybe it would just autogenerate some, just like windows do?

Comment: Indeed, omitting the whole IPv4 config does the job